# Parameter 'Nameddest' in PDF files

Tags: pdf

I'd like to open a PDF at a specific bookmark/outline location by means of the nameddest parameter.
For instance, the following link opens a PDF at the bookmark "Contents":

https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#nameddest=Contents

The following link opens the file at the bookmark "Parameters":
https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#nameddest=Parameters

The following link also opens the file at the bookmark "Parameters":
https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#nameddest=G4.1501771

**From the example above, why nameddest=G4.150177?**

If I already have a PDF file how can I retrieve all the possible values for the nameddest parameter?

Is there a section in the PDF file where I can retrieve all the bookmarks so that I can use them in the nameddest parameter?

I know that the names displayed in the bookmark section are can be different than their actual destinition (PDF specification https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#nameddest=G4.1501771)

Answer (score 1):

First, those parameters don't work in every browser. Safari, for example, doesn't respect them; it just opens to the first page.

Second, Chrome does respect the parameters but considers PDF bookmarks and Named Destinations to be the same thing. So the Named Destination "G4.1501771" and the Bookmark "Parameters" end up going to the same place. PDF Bookmarks and Named Destinations are actually different things. Named Destinations are always a location in the document. PDF Bookmarks can have any number of actions associated with it, one of which is to go to a particular location.

> why nameddest=G4.150177?

Because the PDF was created in Adobe FrameMaker and FrameMaker puts in Named Destinations based on headings automatically. I'm sure they're not random names but they sure look like it.

> Is there a section in the PDF file where I can retrieve all the bookmarks so that I can use them in the nameddest parameter?

Most PDF Viewers will list the bookmarks but Adobe Acrobat will list both Bookmarks and Named Destinations. If you want to do it programmatically, The bookmark tree is a dictionary in the document catalog and can be accessed by many different PDF APIs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it is much clear now. So I guess that I need to look for is that document catalog. I currently have a software writen in ruby that opens a chm help file at a specific section. I wrote the help file in docx and then convert it to chm. I'd like to have the same accessibility but in a pdf file. My docx file has headers than later on get converted to bookmarks in a PDF file.
Any suggestion on a ruby PDF API I can use to get access to the document catalog?

Comment: I don't follow ruby so I can't give you any kind of recommendation.